# How to import markdown into Notion without messy equations

Tags: markdown, notion

When I write a markdown file and import it to notion, it all goes messy. Inline equations within `$...$` is parsed to unicode strings instead of inline quations, and block equations within `$$...$$` is not parsed and presented as-is (meaning I can see the `$$` sign in Notion). Do you encounter this? How to fix it? Or should I stop trying to import markdown into notion?

Comment: Have you seen this guide: https://swimm.io/learn/swimm-vs-notion/markdown-in-notion-quick-guide-and-reference

Answer (score 0):

As of today you can import a markdown file into notion, but the equations won't work. You'll have to retype them by hand

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that full markdown support will be coming to notion
anytime soon (or ever).

In the redit post
[Not so minor gripes](https://www.reddit.com/r/Notion/comments/k7jw6r/not_so_minor_gripes/),
the poster has asked the question:

> Why does notion not follow standard markdown typing shortcuts?

A developer identifying as TheDragonRing has given this excellent answer:

> I think a big reason for this is that notion *isn't* markdown-based,
> it's block/modifier based. They've taken advantage of some markdown
> syntax and recognised that people will often paste markdown and expect
> it to appear a certain way, but a lot of Notion's content is too
> complex to be stored in a markdown format - e.g. toggles, callouts,
> databases, and colours. So even if they didn't need to worry about
> people messing with things, they couldn't expose a page as markdown
> file because markdown isn't actually compatible with Notion's page
> data format.
>
> Then when they're adding a new block type, they consider: what's the
> most user-intuitive way to do this for everyone no matter their
> background. Many people do know markdown, but probably just as many
> don't (though that's not something you'll be able to survey by talking
> to extensive internet users on e.g. reddit). When you see a toggle,
> the thing that makes it stand out from normal text is the arrow, and
> what key looks most like an arrow? A `>`.
>
> That's my understanding of why things are as they are, at least.

According to this text, the notion syntactical concepts are radically
different from markdown. Simple markdown has been implemented for
use by people that work in markdown, but equations are just too
different and too complicated in notion to fully be expressed in
markdown.

You may find more information about the very limited markdown support
in notion in the article
[Markdown in Notion: quick guide and reference](https://swimm.io/learn/swimm-vs-notion/markdown-in-notion-quick-guide-and-reference)
(as suggested in a comment).
You will see that even simple concepts such as Subscript and
Superscript are not supported in markdown, so support for
something as complex as equations is certainly too much to expect
in notion itself.

I have found on github the project of
[Martian: Markdown to Notion Parse](https://github.com/tryfabric/martian)
which claims support for equations, but I don't know
if it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

From what is written in [this Notion help article](https://www.notion.so/help/math-equations),

> Notion uses the [KaTeX library](https://katex.org/) to render math equations, which supports
> a large subset of LaTeX functions.

However, Notion uses the double dollar `$$` qualifier for *inline equations*, while block equations need to be created by typing `/math`and pressing enter (or by clicking on the `+`menu and selecting "block equation".

This evidently creates a problem when importing markdown, which eventually should be addressed by the developer.

As a **workaround**, you can do:

1. for **inline equations**,

> - Highlight an equation in your paragraph.
> - Click the `√x` button in the formatting menu that appears, or use the keyboard shortcut `ctrl/cmd + shift+ E`. Your selected text should
>   turn into an equation.

2. For **block equations**,

- copy or cut the equation
- create a new block by typing `/math` and pressing enter
- click inside the block and paste your equation.

Comment: Interesting. Idealy, I would like to avoid selecting each in every equations from the texts I paste.